# Retrieving rectangle of a list view item

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to get a `CGRect` of a list item view on `onLongPressGesture`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .frame(height: 80)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(.yellow)
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            // here I need to use the rectangle 
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One option would be to crate a separate struct of the list item view and store a state of the rectangle inside it:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    
    let value: Int
    
    @State var rect: CGRect = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
            .frame(height: 80)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
            .background(GeometryReader { gp in
                Color.clear.onAppear{
                    rect = gp.frame(in: .global)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

But unfortunately in the current implementation this is not an option, I need to store coordinates in the list view.

Comment: You may want to look into using a PreferenceKey to transmit that value back up the view hierarchy to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PreferenceKey` worked (thanks @jnpdx for the suggestion). Incase anyone else is wondering how to do it, here is full implementation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var frames = [Int: CGRect]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) { itemID in
                    ItemView(value: itemID)
                        .modifier(FrameModifier())
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            print(frames[itemID])
                        }
                        .onPreferenceChange(FramePreferenceKey.self) {
                            frames[itemID] = $0
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    
    let value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
            .frame(height: 80)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
}

struct FramePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct FrameModifier: ViewModifier {
    private var sizeView: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: FramePreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .global))
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(sizeView)
    }
}
```